# JavaFX Canvas Fonts are all the same

Tags: java, javafx, fonts

I'm trying to write onto the JavaFX canvas. I'm having problems mixing my fonts. I'm using black and white.

```
    Font currentFont = new Font("Georgia",125);
    FontMetrics metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(currentFont);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFont(currentFont);
    float charWidth = metrics.computeStringWidth(jString);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillText(jString, 1, 100, charWidth);
    float charWidthSum = charWidth;

    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFont(new Font("Carlito",60));
    metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(new Font("Carlito",60));
    charWidth = metrics.computeStringWidth(aString);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillText(aString, charWidthSum, 100, charWidth);
    charWidthSum+=charWidth;

    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFont(new Font("Ariel",50));
    metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(new Font("Ariel",50));
    charWidth = metrics.computeStringWidth(vString);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillText(vString, charWidthSum,100, charWidth);
    charWidthSum+=charWidth;

    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFont(new Font("Times",125));
    metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(new Font("Times",125));
    charWidth = metrics.computeStringWidth(a2String);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillText(a2String, charWidthSum, 100, charWidth);


    //HOW TO IMPLEMENT - to collect the content of a string, keeping font type the same
    /*
        public void setPixels(int x, int y, int w, int h,
                      PixelFormat<ByteBuffer> pixelformat,
                      byte buffer[], int offset, int scanlineStride);
     */
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = null;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
    PixelFormat<ByteBuffer> pixelFormat = null;
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter().setPixels(0,0,0,0,null,bytes, 0,0); //write my new character
    //
```

[image]

Will be same font, as I assume I'm just setting the current writeable font. If you see the unimplemented part, I'm considering trying to write the fonts using pixel writer. How to get them into the correct form? I'm using black monotone fonts

Also, I'm aware of TextFlow and StyledTextArea. StyledTextArea is for same height text, and TextFlow is not writable onto canvas, only onto a node. I need canvas functionality, I think.